# Facebook Credit API Error 1383049 on Sandbox Mode Only

Tags: facebook-credits

I am getting ERROR CODE 1383049 when I try opening the Pay Dialogue for Facebook Credit transactions. This error only happens when I ENABLE the Sandbox mode. If I disable it, it works without any problem. It looks like this error is not happening to my other apps, which are in Sandbox mode.

I'm not sure if Facebook developers read this forum, but does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thank you!